# How do I enable the option to "Notify to schedule restart"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have two machines with Windows 10 Home. One of them, in Settings > Update & security > Windows Update > Advanced options, has a drop-down menu where I can choose to automatically install updates whenever available ("Automatic (recommended)") or at a time of my choosing ("Notify to schedule restart"). The other machine, in the same location, does not have that option. How do I get that option to appear in the latter machine?

The machine with this option is on build 10586.679, recently updated from 10586.633. The machine without this option is on build 14393.447.

The machine with this option:

[image: Mini-PC with available option]

The machine without this option:

[image: Laptop without this option]

After updating the older machine to build 14393.0, the Advanced Options screen is just as restricted as the one on the newer machine. How do I restore this vital functionality to both machines?

Comment: Have you checked to see if those two machines are [running the same version and build number of Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/)?  It could simply be that one of them has a feature set that the other hasn't received via an update just yet.

Comment: @Run5k - I haven't looked into the version and build number. The machine that displays this option isn't on very often, and it's downloading some updates now, so it's possible that that option will disappear after that process completes. I'll check for changes at that point.

Comment: If that machine isn't online very often, it's quite possible that is the root cause of the differences.  I would still follow the steps in that tutorial to compare their versions/build numbers for added perspective.

Comment: @Run5k - I installed updates, going from build 10586.633 to build 10586.679, and the option in question is still available. The machine without this option is on build 14393.447. I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: Understood.  Again, that is probably why you are seeing a difference in features... the older machine is running a *very* old version of Windows 10.  If you prefer, there are tools you can download from Microsoft themselves that will allow you to manually initiate the update process.  I have described them in an answer below.

Comment: @Run5k - The older machine is requiring multiple update/restart cycles, so I'll wait and see what its situation is once it's completely done.

Comment: @Run5k - After lots of updates, the older machine is running 14393.0... and now it looks just like the crippleware version. How do I restore that functionality?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding... I thought you meant that the *newer* version had that ability, but the older one didn't.  Essentially, this capability used to be in older versions of Windows 10.  The real answer is that specific function is now gone, but in subsequent versions they have transitioned into something similar.  You now have the ability to [configure Active Hours](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/46468-windows-update-active-hours-change-windows-10-a.html) on your system so that it won't reboot within that designated time frame (up to a maximum of 12 hours).

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be that one of them has a feature set that the other hasn't received via an update just yet.

Since the one lacking the feature you seek is actually running a much older version of Windows 10, you could either wait for Windows Update to bring it up-to-speed with the latest version, or you could potentially download Microsoft's [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) (or [Windows 10 Disc Image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/)) to expedite the Windows 10 update process.

**Edit**:  it appears that this capability existed in versions of Windows 10 prior to the Anniversary Update.  In the aftermath, they have modified the Windows Update system to allow us to set *Active Hours*, configuring a time frame up to 12 hours when the system won't reboot following any updates.

The bottom line is that the specific capability to enable `"Notify to schedule restart"` doesn't exist in the most recent builds of Windows 10.